# Caching in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I m having a webService.
In that I m using Caching.

I have wrote following code to store datatable in cache.

```
using System.Web.Caching;

Cache.Insert("dt", dt, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
```

It give me error like "An object Reference is required for non static field.

How can i remove this error

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use Cache class as an static one.

If you want to use current Cache class instance for an HTTP context during a request, you should be doing something like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("dt", dt, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx).Insert(...). This 'Cache' is a property returning an *instance* of System.Web.Caching.Cache. It's the same as HttpContext.Current.Cache, but without requiring an HttpContext.

Your code was trying to access a method of that class, without using an instance - thus the error message.